# Do I need permission to send activity to Google Maps search?

Tags: android, google-maps

I have an android app and I don't want to build my own maps.
I just want to send the address to Google Maps with:

```
Uri IntentUri = Uri.parse("geo:0,0?q=" + GETcity+ "," + GETstreet +" "+GEThouseNumber);
Intent mapIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, IntentUri);
startActivity(mapIntent);
```

1. Do I need any permissions for that?
2. Is this an ok way to do it, or there a better way to build my own map?

Answer (score 0):

> does i need some permissions for that ?

When you launch another application to handle some task (such as taking a picture or getting the user's location), you do not need any permissions. The app you are launching is responsible for requesting the appropriate permissions.

> that is ok to do it ? or its better to build my own map.. ?

This is completely up to you. If the defaults map applications provide all the functionality you want, then you probably don't need to worry about it. If you are worried that the user won't have a map app installed, or you want to provide some UI elements that the default applications don't offer, you may want to make one yourself.

Personally, I don't want to deal with the complexities that come with creating a mapping application.

Answer (score 0):

No permissions needed.
If you wish to implement the Maps API, then you will need to add the specific dependencies and include the Locations permissions.